# Combining multiple PDFs to specific layout

Tags: pdf, autocad

I am trying to laser cut multiple signs, and I need to combine PDFs into a single PDF for import into AutoCAD. The signs are all the same shape, but I need to populate the different text/image for each in the frame.

I have experience with python, and I am open to learning a new tool/software to get this done in the easiest manner possible. I would love any guidance or advice on this project.

[Here is a very basic picture of how I would like the final PDF to be.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jgb83.png)

Comment: [What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The PDF toolkit (pdftk) can merge PDFs and change pagination and/or put multiple pages onto a single page.

https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/